# XLPagerTabStrip как передать данные между дочерними контроллерами?

Tags: ios, swift, menu, uiviewcontroller

Всем привет дорогие друзья. Я начинающий программист, нужна помощь. Я использую XlPagerTabStrip. У меня есть два дочерних контроллера child1 и child2 мне нужно передать некоторые данные из child2 в child1 и к тому же при этом программно перейти в child1 и отобразить полученные данные, как я могу это сделать ? В моем случае segue не подходит. Есть функция moveToViewController для перехода из одного дочернего контроллера в другой, но как мне передать данные?

Comment: что насчет использования делегатов, отправки уведомлений или создания общего хранилища (в виде класса или базы данных) для хранения общих данных?

Comment: я объявил глобальную переменную в appDelegate. Храню данные в userDefaults в viewController я вытаскиваю массив из userDefaults.В Child2 - есть UITableViewController при нажатий на элемент списка я хочу передать индекс нажатого элемента  в Child1 и хочу отобразить массив[index] (т.к массив у меня глобальный) и при всем этом мне программно нужно перейти в Child1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я уже указал в комментарии, для передачи данных между вью контроллерами можно использовать различные распространенные техники, по большому счету не зависящие от конкретных компонентов - делегирование, уведомления и тд

Конкретно для данной библиотеки вы можете переопределить в подклассе метод `moveToViewController(at index: Int, animated: Bool = true)` и обновлять данные в дочерних вью контроллерах по их индексу, используя предварительно сохраненные данные (например в `UserDefaults`)

```
class StripViewController: ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController {

    override func viewControllers(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController] {
        [ViewController1.initViewController(with: pagerTabStripController),
         ViewController2.initViewController(with: pagerTabStripController)]
    }

    override func moveToViewController(at index: Int, animated: Bool = true) {
        super.moveToViewController(at: index)

        if (index == 0) {
            let vc = viewControllers[index] as! ViewController1
            // обновляем данные в vc
            // vc.updateSomething()
        }
    }

}
```

Либо можно это делать в самих вью контроллерах, используя встроенные методы, например

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        updateSomething()
    }

    override func didMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) {
        if (parent == nil) {
            return
        }

        updateSomething()
    }

    func updateSomething() {
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно !